# How to use oAuth authentication in JSONModel.loadData()

Tags: oauth-2.0, sapui5, jsonmodel

I am using oAuth authentication for the first time and finding some challenges in implementing a working code.

I tried using ajax calls but failed.

The idea is - my java service is enabled with oAuth2.0 and I have my callback URL, my Auth URL, my token URL and also the client id and client secret, but how do I put it all together to get a workable code?

Any samples would help -

Either AJAX call (jQuery) to put in my UI5 application or even better with JSONModel.loadData().

Comment: Get you token first and then include it in your follow up request. Are you retrieving your token at least?

Comment: Hi @bernard - apologies, but not sure of the syntax and flow as its my first time with JSONModel - if you could direct me to a working sample or some proper link, it would be of great help.